# Start services over incoming SMS in android

Tags: android

As per my requirement I want to start/stop services over incoming SMS.

As per Dinesh idea I did this.

```
public class ReceiveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Boolean SendSMS;
    String Mobileno;
    String VarMessageBody;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                Mobileno = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                VarMessageBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                Mobileno = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

            }
            if (VarMessageBody.startsWith("START")) {
                Intent intentHome = new Intent(context,SwitchBluetoothActivity.class);
                intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intentHome);

            }

        }

    }
```

and in my SwitchBluetoothActivity i have written

```
public class SwitchBluetoothActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    private ToggleButton tb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bluetoothText);
        tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

        final BluetoothAdapter bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (bta == null) {
            tv.setText("Device does not support Bluetooth");
        }
        else if(bta.isEnabled()){
            tv.setText("Bluetooth is enabled");
            tb.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            tv.setText("Bluetooth is disabled");
            tb.setChecked(false);
        }

        tb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(bta.isEnabled()){
                    bta.disable();
                tv.setText("Bluetooth is disabled");
                }
                else{
                    bta.enable();
                tv.setText("Bluetooth is enabled");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But i am not able to start this activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Register BroadcastReceiver Class in your Project listen the incoming sms tutorial and code Below link

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/

after Broadcast Receiver Class listen receive sms to Start Activity sample code below:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReceiveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    MapMarker obj_gps = new MapMarker();
    Boolean SendSMS;
    String Mobileno;
    String VarMessageBody;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";            
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    Mobileno=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    VarMessageBody=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                    Mobileno=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

                }
               //---display the new SMS message---
               if (VarMessageBody.startsWith("START"))//Check Message Body String Start with START
                    Intent intentHome = new Intent(context, HomeScreen.class);
                    intentHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    //intentHome.putExtra("No",Mobileno);
                    //intentHome.putExtra("Msg",VarMessageBody);
                    //intentHome.putExtra("Mob", Mobileno);
                    context.startActivity(intentHome);
              }

              Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }



}
```

This code Receive Send SMS FORMAT "START" To Start Activity..!

**Note:I am Start Activity only you Start Service on if condition...!**

Comment: Hi @Dinesh  today i tried your given code but did not able to start the Activity.

Comment: you have Register BroadcastReceiver in your android manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Regist an BroadcastReceiver that when the Sms incoming. you can start the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast receiver for incoming sms 
and in that receiver you can put your logic of start and stop service baswed on content of sms and you have to also setup a logic of services remain startup after device shutdown and restart and for that you can use  broadcast receiver of of device restart

for start and stop service refer this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html